.map function in react is bringing a error
I am writing this code in which i have to map an array in some divs...
there is first code which has the mapping and the ui
import { useContext } from "react";
import "./index.scss";
import { PlaygroundContext } from "../../../Providers/PlaygroundProvider";
// import { logo } from "./logo.png"
// import { vlogo } from "./vlogo.png";


const Folder = ({folderTitle, cards}) =>{
      <div className="folder-container">
                 <div className="folder-header">
                    <div className="folder-header-item">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined" style={{color: "yellow"}}>{{folderTitle}}</span>
                    <span>{"Folder 1"}</span>
                     </div>
                    <div className="folder-header-item">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
                    <button>
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">add</span>
                    <span>New File</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="cards-container">
                {
                  cards?.map((file, index) => {
                    return(  <div className="card" key={index}>
                      {/* Logo=> <span class="material-symbols-outlined">article</span> */}
                      <img src={require('./vlogo.png')} />
                        <div className="title-container">
                            <span>{file?.title}</span>
                            <span>Language: {file?.language} </span>
                         </div>
                        <div style={{display: 'flex', gap: '10px'}}>
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>)
                  })
                }
            </div>
          </div>
} 

export const RightComponent = () => {
  
  const folders = useContext(PlaygroundContext);
  console.log(folders); 


    return(
        <div className="right-container">
            <div className="header">
                Code Projects
                <button className="add-folder">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined">add</span>
                    <span>New Folder</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {
                  folders?.map((folder, index) => {
                    return<Folder folderTitle={folder.title} key={index} cards={folders.files}/>;
                  })  
            }
        

        </div>
    );
}

and here is the container
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {v4} from 'uuid';

export const PlaygroundContext = createContext();

const initialData = [
    {
        id:v4(),
        title: 'DSA',
        files: [
            {
                title: 'codewala',
                id:v4(),
                language: 'cpp',
                code:':Ldkidm'
            },
            {
                title: 'codewala2',
                id:v4(),
                language: 'cpp',
                code:':Ldkidmccccccc'
            }
            
        ]

    }
]

export const PlaygroundProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [folders, setFolders] = useState(initialData);


    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(folders))
    },[])
    const uniqId = v4();
    // console.log(uniqId);
    const obj = {name: 'divyansh'};
    return( 
//  <>{children}</>
    <PlaygroundContext.Provider value={{folders}}> 
    {children}
</PlaygroundContext.Provider>
    );
};

I dont why but the mapping is showing error
the error is
folders.map is not a function
TypeError: folders.map is not a function
    at RightComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:428:78)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24807:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28778:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30081:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15063:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15107:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15164:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35062:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34310:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34233:9)

I tried stringfying the JSON Data but isnt helping
I also saw other questions of stackoverflow but they arent helping

value={{folders}} looks suspicious... What does that console.log(folders); tell you?

If folders.map is not a function then folders is not an array.  .map() is a function on arrays.  When the error occurs, what is folders?  What did you expect it to be?  Why?

@Andy thanks for the response, and yes that removed the error but now it is not showing the map in all... what can be changed.. Also the console.log gives me the array that i made in the second code

Instead of:
const folders = useContext(PlaygroundContext);
You should write:
const {folders} = useContext(PlaygroundContext);

@JovanKecojevic no it isnt making any change, the problem got solved when i changed the value ={{folders}} but now there should be some cards on the page which were in the container js file which isnt coming, i think that the data isnt getting mapped or something, kindly help me!

Also when you introduced the  component, you passed cards:{folders.files} instead of {folder.files} (get the files value from the element not the array).

@JovanKecojevic I am new coder, i dont really understand what do you mean, can tell me what I can change for the code to work?

There are a few problems here that I'll go over, and then supply a "working" example of data at the end.

{{folderTitle}} should just be {folderTitle}.
class should always be className.
In your component call you're using cards={folders.files} when it should be cards={folder.files} ("folder" singular, as you're picking up the folder variable from the callback)
Your Provider value should be value={folders}.
I've swapped out the map index in favour of using your object ids instead (see the pitfall section here on why).
Multiple child elements need to be wrapped in a parent element - this is why there's an extra section element in the Folder component.



const { useState, useContext, createContext } = React;

const initialData = [
  {
    id:1,
    title: 'DSA',
    files: [
      {
        title: 'codewala',
        id:2,
        language: 'cpp',
        code:':Ldkidm'
      },
      {
        title: 'codewala2',
        id:3,
        language: 'cpp',
        code:':Ldkidmccccccc'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const PlaygroundContext = createContext();

function PlaygroundProvider({ children }) {
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState(initialData);

  return ( 
    <PlaygroundContext.Provider value={folders}>
      {children}
    </PlaygroundContext.Provider>
  );
}


function Folder({ folderTitle, cards }) {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="folder-container">
        <div className="folder-header">
          <div className="folder-header-item">
            <span className="material-symbols-outlined" style={{color: "yellow"}}>{folderTitle}</span>
            <span>Folder 1</span>
          </div>
          <div className="folder-header-item">
            <span className="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
            <span className="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
            <button>
              <span className="material-symbols-outlined">add</span>
              <span>New File</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="cards-container">
        {cards.map((file) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={file.id}>
              <div className="title-container">
                <span>{file.title}</span>
                <span>Language: {file.language}</span>
              </div>
              <div style={{display: 'flex', gap: '10px'}}>
                <span className="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                <span className="material-symbols-outlined">edit</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

function App() {

  const folders = useContext(PlaygroundContext);

  return (
    <main>
      {folders.map((folder) => {
        return (
          <Folder
            key={folder.id}
            folderTitle={folder.title}
            cards={folder.files}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );

}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
const Root = () => (
  <PlaygroundProvider>
    <App />
  </PlaygroundProvider>
);
root.render(<Root />);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



